# Web API post deserializing json result but all properties null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, model-binding

I've been scratching my head on this one for a few days now.

Using the angular `$http` service I'm posting back to an api controller passing the `Movie` json object. And while the correct action is hit, **all of the models properties, primitives and complex, are null or default**. I've used the `JsonProperty` attribute because the json objects properties have different names than the c# model that I need to deserialize to. I've also tried using `DataContract`, being sure to set `UseDataContractJsonSerializer` to `true` on app start, but that had no effect also.

I should also note that I'm using web api 2.2.

Simplified Model:

```
public class Movie {

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "release_dates")]
    public ReleaseDates ReleaseDates { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ratings")]
    public Ratings Ratings { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "abridged_cast")]
    public ICollection<Character> Cast { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "users")]
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(Movie movie) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Call from the client (in debug I can see that the movie js object is hydrated with the proper data):

```
$http.post('/api/usermovies', { movie : movie });
```

This is the content in the request being sent from angular:

```
{
    "movie" : {
        "id" : "12897",
        "title" : "The Matrix",
        "year" : 1999,
        "release_dates" : {
            "theater" : "1999-03-31",
            "dvd" : "1999-09-21"
        },
        "ratings" : {
            "critics_rating" : "Certified Fresh",
            "critics_score" : 87,
            "audience_rating" : "Upright",
            "audience_score" : 85
        },
        "abridged_cast" : [{
                "name" : "Keanu Reeves",
                "id" : "162654049",
                "characters" : ["Neo"]
            }, {
                "name" : "Laurence Fishburne",
                "id" : "162669090",
                "characters" : ["Morpheus"]
            }, {
                "name" : "Carrie-Anne Moss",
                "id" : "162669130",
                "characters" : ["Trinity"]
            }, {
                "name" : "Hugo Weaving",
                "id" : "162709905",
                "characters" : ["Agent Smith"]
            }, {
                "name" : "Gloria Foster",
                "id" : "364627698",
                "characters" : ["The Oracle"]
            }
        ],
        "$$hashKey" : "00C"
    }
}
```

Tracing doesn't really turn up anything. The modelBinder seems to be properly associating the json with the correct model...

> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=POST, Url=http://www.moovy.com/api/usermovies, Message='http://www.moovy.com/api/usermovies'
>
> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='UserMovies', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
>
> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Moovy.Api.Controllers.UserMoviesController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
>
> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Moovy.Api.Controllers.UserMoviesController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
>
> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'Post(Movie movie)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
>
> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Value read='Moovy.Models.Movie'', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync
>
> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'movie' bound to the value 'Moovy.Models.Movie'', Operation=FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
>
> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: movie=Moovy.Models.Movie', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync

What to do, what to do?

Comment: Good question, lots of detail. Probably helped yourself by doing all that work to write a good question.

Comment: How did you get that trace? I would love to see how my webapi controller is deserializing a model I'm passing in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. This was because of a mistake in how I was passing the movie object in the request.

This...

```
$http.post('/api/usermovies', { movie : movie });
```

Should be changed to this...

```
$http.post('/api/usermovies', movie);
```

Deserialization from the json object with differing property names into the `Movie` object is working perfectly after that change.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be like this, in VS edit paste special , Paste Json as classes

```
public class Rootobject
{
public Movie movie { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string title { get; set; }
public int year { get; set; }
public Release_Dates release_dates { get; set; }
public Ratings ratings { get; set; }
public Abridged_Cast[] abridged_cast { get; set; }
public string hashKey { get; set; }
}

public class Release_Dates
{
public string theater { get; set; }
public string dvd { get; set; }
}

public class Ratings
  {
public string critics_rating { get; set; }
public int critics_score { get; set; }
public string audience_rating { get; set; }
public int audience_score { get; set; }
}

public class Abridged_Cast
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string[] characters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I notice that some of the types in your model are different than mine, but if it were a type issue would the properties with matching types be deserailized properly? Only the incorrect types would be null or default.

Comment: so where exactly is it crashing ? are you able to view props inside your post method ?

Comment: it's not crashing. The json is being bound to the correct model but all the model properties are null or default.

Comment: Hmmm, might be worth trying the class in that case ?